# SSO Support for Rally RestAPI jar

Tags: rally

I have come across a post where SSO is supported or can be used using Rally.RestApi.dll, and C#. Below is the link 
[How to SSO using Rally.RestApi.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055043/how-to-sso-using-rally-restapi-dll/)

Excel plugin available in Rally website works fine even with SSO. Then this should even work with Java Rest API, I believe.

But I would like to know whether Rally RestAPI.jar for Java can be used for SSO enabled Rally or not.

Is there any tips or tricks that can be employed to make it work?

I want to generate a customized rally report for my team. I am using Java and RallyRestAPI.jar for this.
Please suggest & help

Answer (score 0):

**C#**

Rally Excel and VisualStudio plugins support SSO, and the next version of dll for the [.NET toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET) will eventually replace the currently available dll v2.0.1, which is a year old. The new dll will use the SSO mechanism used in Rally Visual Studio plugin, and not the one implemented in current version of Excel plugin, and eventually Excel plugin will be updated with that mechanism as well. A timeframe for all this is not available yet.

**Java**

There is currently no work in progress and no plans to add SSO support for [Rally Rest toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava).
It means that if your Rally subscription allows either a hybrid authentication (SSO and Rally authentication) or SSO with exceptions, your java code can use basic Rally authentication. In the former case your api user account has to be added to the exceptions list by your subscription administrator.