# How to use Rally APIs for SSO authentication from C# desktop application

Tags: rally

I also tried REST API, but couldnt able to authrorize. 
restApi = new RallyRestApi(mailId,"", "https://rally1.rallydev.com/", "v2.0");

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty thorough intro to using SSO with Rally's C# .NET dll in this prior answer:

[How to SSO using Rally.RestApi.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055043/how-to-sso-using-rally-restapi-dll)

Note that the API has been updated substantially since this answer was posted, so you may need to adjust your code correspondingly.