# CA Agile Excel Add In

Tags: rally

I m QA guy, we recently migrated to Rally and we have some hard time in creating test case in Rally as it is time consuming work so thought of using the Excel Add In for Rally. I have installed the Add In but I m not able to connect to Rally via the Add In. In our client location we have IE 9 for Windows 7 OS, so when I tried to connect Rally through Single Sign on, it doesn't connect it says Rally does not support this browser. I dont know, I changed the default browser setting to Chrome it connects only IE 9. If I click on CA Agile Central Help button from the add in, it gets opened in Chrome browser. Please suggests me the solution for this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This answer:

[How to use SSO with Rally REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055043/how-to-sso-using-rally-restapi-dll) gives a bit of insight into how the Excel plugin raises the Rally SSO Login form. It uses a .NET WinForms dialog with a "browser" component to present the SSO dialog to the user.

As the dialog component is .NET, it can only instantiate an IE browser frame using whatever version of IE is currently installed.

Because of this, and because Rally [supports only the current version of IE](https://help.rallydev.com/supported-web-browsers), it will be necessary to upgrade IE to a modern version, in order for you to use the Excel Add-in with SSO.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I don't think I can upgrade IE in client machine so I have no options.